# parse table created at runtime by calling document.write() from JavaScript

Tags: html, html-parsing

i am making an iphone app and i want to download and parse a tables from html web page .this tables are created by JavaScript at runtime (i think when the page loaded) ,so i can see theme with safari Browser's Developer Tools ,but when i try to download the html code the source that I get contains no html tags of that tables ,this is my html code

```
<table dir = "rtl .......">
<tbody>
<script src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=ajax&rev=3"......>
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=mc&rev=6"></script>
<script>..</script>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
```

the question is how to access them ?

this is the page i want to parse :[html page](http://kooora.com/?c=6423)

Answer (score 0):

if you can use JQuery Library,
then you can get your dynamic table in document ready event.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

example:

```
$(function(){
 var table = $('[dir="rtl"]')
});
```

Code assume that table has dir="rtl" attribute. Everything  in jquery doc.

Comment: thanks Kamil but i am new to html parsing .so how i can use JQuery Library in iphone app ,if there any example .and sorry of my english

Comment: Ok i think i misunderstand you. In that case you should use kind of "browser control" from Iphone SDK and than browser (run JS) you can attatch to event and get html markup. Sorry I'am not familliar with Iphone sdk. Or use externals API that can run JS (if such exists :))